# Multiple Screen support in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Im Looking for the best route to fix my layouts for multiple screen size on android. I have a great app that is almost ready for launch .. However one of my partners tried it on an Samsung Tablet and the Icons and some features are too small

So What i was thinking do I make the resolution change on screen size or is there a simpler method ?

Here is my layout code Any Suggestion will help  ?

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.waysecure"
xmlns:bm="com.example.waysecure"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_pannic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pannic"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Fofo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
 <SlidingDrawer
 android:id="@+id/sg_below"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="275dp"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
 android:content="@+id/content"
 android:handle="@+id/handle" >
<Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="60dp" android:id="@+id/handle" android:background="@drawable/tray_handle_normal" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="282dp"
    android:background="#aa000000" >
        </RelativeLayout><TabHost  android:id="@+id/content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#aa000000" >
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


            </LinearLayout>
              <GridView
                  android:id="@+id/tab2"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                  android:columnWidth="90dp"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                  android:verticalSpacing="1dp" > 
            </GridView>  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                  <com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel android:id="@+id/carousel2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:animationDuration="200" pj:Items="@array/entries" pj:Names="@array/names" pj:SelectedItem="0" pj:UseReflection="true">
                </com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel>  
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" >
        </TabWidget>
    </TabHost>
</SlidingDrawer>
</merge>
```

Comment: @Jhono James Put proper images in all drawable folder according to sizes .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put extra layouts in res folder for different screens.

If you want `7 inch` Create layout folder in res name as `layout-sw720dp`

For `10 inch` create `layout-xlarge`

copy the all files from `layout` folder and paste files and adjust the size.

convert and test with all screen's.

Please refer link for more screen's

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Only thing you have to do is add the `<support-screens>`  in your `manifest` and below is the  `<support-screens>`:

```
 <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Tips for Creating consistent layouts:

1. Dont hard-code any `layout` parameters such as `width`,`height`,etc..
2. Dont use "`px`".Use "`sp`" for Text Size and "`dp`" for `layout-width`, `layout-height` etc.
3. Make use of `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` and dont use `AbsoluteLayout` as it is deprecated.
4. Use `ScrollView` wherever required for `layouts` as it supports for a singleView.

For more information check the Android Developer documents of [Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 2):

I configured a way for this. For me, it was an hit and trial method. Same problem happened to me when i was developing my [first android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recipe.pack) but in the end, i nailed it. For supporting every screen resolution perfectly, in the case of full screen image, make 4 images of different resolutions:

```
hdpi: 480*800
ldpi: 320*460
mdpi:720*960
xhdpi: 800*1280
```

if your app supports both orientations, then make different layout for the landscape mode and place it with the same name in layout-land and related information can be found on this [link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html&ei=8wQvUYCyJcrRrQf-pIGoBw&usg=AFQjCNHemvlQ2sNEATp3v6KONvL52P-N7A&bvm=bv.42965579,d.bmk).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create layout_size folder in res folder

> for different size screens create diffrent xml files.

Answer (score 0):

please reffer this..it may be help you..fend[image: device screens and resolutions]